# jquery - Use split to split only text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

My code splits the text and place a html code after a certain number of words. It's working, the problem is that the split function not only splits text, but also splits HTML. How can I configure it to split text only? Let's say I have an article and I need a banner to appear in the middle of the article, if I don't take care, I'll split some div or something like that.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {


var wordList = $(".newsitem_text").html().split(' ');
var newHtml = '';

$.each(wordList, function(index, word){
  newHtml += ' ' + word;
  if (index == 10) {
    newHtml += 'Some HTML goes here'     
  }        
})
;

$(".newsitem_text").html(newHtml);

});

</script>
```

Comment: did you try $(".newsitem_text").text().split(' ');

Comment: Tried it, almost the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery's `.contents()` method and split only text tags while copying everything else verbatim. Something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var newHtml = '';
  var count = 0;

  function check() {
    if (count >= 20) {
      newHtml += 'Some HTML goes here'     
      count = 0;
    }
  }

  $(".newsitem_text").contents().each(function () {

    if (this.nodeType != 3) {
      newHtml += this.outerHTML;
      count += $(this).text().trim().split(/\s+/).length;
    }
    else {
      var wordList = $(this).text().trim().split(/\s+/);

      $.each(wordList, function(index, word){
        count++;
        check();
        newHtml += ' ' + word;
      })
    }

  });

  check();

  $(".newsitem_text").html(newHtml);

});
```

Comment: and remove the `  jQuery(function($) { var wordList = $(".newsitem_text").text().split(' ');
 ` ???

Comment: Wrap it all in `jQuery(function($) { })`, yes, but remove the rest.

Comment: Did that, all I got was some html wrapped `undefined .colunasocial1 { padding-left:4px;} .centralizasocial { margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto} Tweetar !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"); (function(d, s,Some HTML goes here id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return;`

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it place the html after the html close tags? For example place after `>`, like placing after `</script>` or `</div>`

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be nodeType *not equal* to three. Edited. Works for me now. Not sure I understand your last comment.

Comment: Ah, got it. You want to place something right afrer every non-text node? Just add whatever you want in the first if condition, e.g. `newHtml += this.outerHTML + 'and so on';`

Comment: This code is splitting the html source. If I configure it to appear after 40 words, it will not only count the words, but also the whole html, for example I have the code `This is <a> Link </a>`, this is counted as 5 words, so if I configure the code to appear after the 3 word `<a>`, it will appear inside the link. Got it?

Comment: Can you move this conversation to a chat?

Comment: Edited it to do what you want.

Comment: It's because I have no idea on how to make the change that you suggested.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214099/jquery-split-at-html-tags-i-e-split-at-every-instance-of-the-h2-tags

Comment: What are you having a problem with exactly? I already did all the changes in the answer, the code should just work.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see before. Just tested the code and it is working, but it is repeating the images, like a loop.